# Android - How to make fragment transition animation with toolbar using getChildFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, child-fragment

I try to implement a navigator object. It has own stack.

My activity layout hierarchy is below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My fragment hierarchy is here:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragmentRootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContentLayout">
</FrameLayout>
```

To replace fragmentA and fragmentB with animation, toolbar is animated when I use getSupportFragmentManager of activity.

But this is not fit for my requirement. Because I want each navigator to has a different stack. So, I use below code with animation(right to left)

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentRootLayout, fragment);
```

But toolbar doesn't slide right to left.

Comment: Yes, As you added the Toolbar to My Fragment. And After that, you replace the fragment inside the `My Fragment`. So Toolbar remains on his position.

Comment: Why? I replace the child fragment with the top layout of parent fragment. If this is expected behaviour, how can I slide the toolbar using fragment navigator?

Comment: You need to add animation on it.

Comment: I don't know how to slide toolbar with fragment transition. Please, give me an example link. I couldn't find :/